# Connecting spring boot app to datastax/dse-server container, getting "cassandra-service did not send an authentication challenge"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to connect my java spring boot application to the datastax/dse-server container with docker-compose, but I got this error: Invalid keyspace. And my cassandra service returns : cassandra-service/172.22.0.2:9042 did not send an authentication challenge; This is suspicious because the driver expects authentication.
This is a part of my application.properties:

```
#configure Cassandra database  
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=cassandra-service
spring.data.cassandra.cluster=***-cluster
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=***
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=dc1
spring.data.cassandra.rackid=rack1
spring.data.cassandra.username=***@gmail.com
spring.data.cassandra.password=*****

# Credentials to Astra DB
astra.client-id= ******
astra.client-secret= ******
astra.api.application-token=*******

# Select an Astra instance
astra.api.database-region= europe-west1
astra.api.database-id= *****
astra.api.keyspace= *****
astra.api.grpc.enabled=true
astra.cql.enabled=true
astra.cql.driver-config.basic.session-keyspace=****
# Astra DB secure connection bundle: place in resources folder
datastax.astra.auth-provider.class = PlainTextAuthProvider
datastax.astra.auth-provider.username = ***@gmail.com
datastax.astra.auth-provider.password = *****

datastax.astra.secure-connect-bundle=secure-connect-db.zip
```

This is a part of my docker-compose.yml:

```
cassandra-service:
    image: datastax/dse-server:6.8.3
    container_name: cassandra-container
    hostname: cassandra-service
    ports:
    - 9042:9042
    networks:
    - ***-network
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./secure-connect-clicknrate.zip:/secrets/secure-connect-clicknrate.zip
    environment:
    - DS_LICENSE=accept
    - DS_PUBLIC=1
    - DS_USERNAME=***@gmail.com
    - DS_PASSWORD=*******
    - DS_KEYSPACE=***
    - DS_SECURE_CONNECT_BUNDLE=/secrets/secure-connect-db.zip
    - CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=cassandra-service
    - CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE=****
    - CASSANDRA_PORT=9042
    - CASSANDRA_SCHEMA_ACTION=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
    - CASSANDRA_DATACENTER=dc1
    - astra.cql.driver-config.basic.session-keyspace=****
```

And this is a part of my pom.xml:

```
<!-- Cassandra Database Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running a [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) instance:

```
cassandra-service:
    image: datastax/dse-server:6.8.3
```

but you are passing credentials for an [Astra database](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) instance:

```
    - DS_SECURE_CONNECT_BUNDLE=/secrets/secure-connect-db.zip
```

Astra credentials are not compatible with DSE and you cannot use an Astra secure-connect bundle with DSE.

In any case, the Cassandra Java driver reported the warning because you supplied a username and password but the cluster/instance you're connecting to doesn't have authentication enabled.

This is expected behaviour from the Java driver to warn you in case you have connected to the wrong cluster. Cheers!

Comment: So what is the docker image that I must use for an astra database instance please?

Comment: Astra DB is a fully-managed Cassandra-as-a-service so by definition, there isn't a Docker image for it. Cheers!